# implement digital signature etoken in web application

Tags: java, digital-signature

I want something like this-

1. The user will access form on my webpage (aspx page) and fill the form. (this is a small form with four textboxes for entry).
2. User will plugin his **digital signature etoken** in his PC (client machine).
3. My java applet will sign the data entered (can produce hash of that data if possible) on form using private key of the client's digital signature which is present in client's etoken.
4. And send the signed data to the server

I am new in java.. kindly share some code if possible...
(at server side asp.net application is running which will verify the signature and collect the data if signature is verified)(public key is stored in database for signature verification)

Plz provide me some solution...

Comment: _Plz provide me some solution_ NO, people won't write code for you. Please try yourself and come back if you have any "specific" problem.

Comment: Java supports PKCS11 interface and (on Windows) CryptoAPI interface. Both are available for applets. Search for information about this support and implement it.

Comment: @Lovely I am currently trying to build something like that for my web app. If you had progress in yours could we talk in chat,ask you a few things? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553377/how-to-make-a-digital-signature-in-a-web-application-javascript-using-a-smartc):
Real e-goverment solution to solve this: 1) Install a local Java application on the user's PC. The application listens on a port as, for example 5678 2) In your page, javascript detects whether there is support for applets 3) If there is no support, connects to the application in the form http://127.0.01:5678/sign and sends the data to sign. 4) The application is local and has no trouble using the operating system keystore, which includes drivers PKCS # 11. Make digital signature and prepares the result 5) page javascript periodically query the result and retrieves it when ready.
I'm currently developing a solution like. Can inform briefly after implementing successfully.
See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37421135/3109698) also.